# jquery UI autocomplete displays empty list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

The autocomplete list is displaying empty results. I have other autocomplete fields on the page that are working fine.

[empty autocomplete list picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34U5A.png)

I checked the data source (an array) and the data is there (see below, none of the data contains an "A")

[not autocompleting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiUpk.png)

EDIT:here is the code

```
var scarTable =['F8-2015-0001','F8-2015-0002','F8-2015-0003'] //this is actually populated from a query but I put this in as example data to show the format    
$("#reoccuranceId").autocomplete({
                    source: scarTable,
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            if(!ui.item){                           
                                $(this).val("");
                            }
                       }
                })
```

Below is the modified DOM, there is indeed no list populating

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 1074px; left: 323px; width: 227px;">
<li class="ui-widget-content ui-menu-divider"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: The first picture shows 2 results. But they seem to be empty or hidden. Have you checked your CSS and the manipulated DOM with element inspector?